# How do I get MVC to find my controller path?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, controller, asp.net-mvc-partialview, renderaction

I am trying to call an action for a partial view in my `_Layout` view.  If I place the action in the home controller, it works, but if I create a new controller `StatusController`, place the same child action method in it and call it from the `_Layout` view I get an error:

> The Contoller path '/' was not found or does not implement
>   IController.

from layout view `_Layout.cshtml` I call the action like so:

```
 @{Html.RenderAction("_GetforStatus", "StatusController");}
```

`_GetforStatus()` is the child action method inside the `StatusController`, as well as the name of the partial view.

How can i get ASP.NET MVC 4 to find my new controller?

Comment: Do you have any Areas?

Comment: I'm really new to this...  I honestly don't know what you mean by "areas," so I am guessing the answer is "no."

Comment: Have you tried `@{Html.RenderAction("_GetforStatus", "Status");}` without the `Controller` in the controller name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass controller name without **Controller** postfix to make it work.The framework itself will exectue that Controller's action

Write like this:

```
@{Html.RenderAction{"_GetforStatus", "Status");}
```

or you can also use this:

```
@Html.Action("_GetforStatus","Status")
```

Comment: without @haim770 it was typing mistake

Answer (score 2):

The post-pended Controller moniker is implied.  Also, check your parentheses.  Try below to render the partial in the Layout.

```
 @{Html.RenderPartial("_GetforStatus", "Status");}
```